# Getting Exception in Admin Server using Spring boot3.x.x, cannot register service on sdmin server

Tags: java, spring, microservices

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Failed to resolve 'Shruti.mshome.net' \[A(1), AAAA(28)\] after 6 queries
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136) \~\[spring-webflux-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4\]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
\*\__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET health \[DefaultWebClient\]
Original Stack Trace:
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136) \~\[spring-webflux-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4\]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4563) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onError(FluxPeek.java:222) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:205) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:229) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:279) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWrite.java:121) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.maybeOnError(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:327) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:212) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.drain(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:476) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor$EmitterInner.drainParent(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:620) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PubSubInner.request(FluxPublish.java:874) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:337) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$DeferredSubscription.request(Operators.java:1743) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:196) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:205) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:311) \~\[reactor-netty-http-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16\]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:205) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:172) \~\[reactor-netty-core-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16\]
at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.AbstractPool$Borrower.fail(AbstractPool.java:488) \~\[reactor-netty-core-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16\]
at reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.SimpleDequePool.lambda$drainLoop$9(SimpleDequePool.java:436) \~\[reactor-netty-core-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(FluxDoOnEach.java:186) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:205) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnectionAllocator$PooledConnectionInitializer.onError(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:583) \~\[reactor-netty-core-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16\]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:241) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:315) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4563) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3\]
at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:576) \~\[reactor-netty-core-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16\]
at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.lambda$doResolveAndConnect$11(TransportConnector.java:375) \~\[reactor-netty-core-1.1.16.jar:1.1.16\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:557) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure(DefaultPromise.java:110) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver$2.operationComplete(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:86) \~\[netty-resolver-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1133) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1072) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:444) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.onResponse(DnsResolveContext.java:675) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$500(DnsResolveContext.java:68) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:502) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.trySuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:345) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.finishSuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:336) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver$DnsResponseHandler.channelRead(DnsNameResolver.java:1382) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) \~\[netty-codec-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:97) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) \~\[na:na\]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'Shruti.mshome.net' \[A(1), AAAA(28)\] after 6 queries
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1125) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1072) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:444) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.onResponse(DnsResolveContext.java:675) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$500(DnsResolveContext.java:68) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:502) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.trySuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:345) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.finishSuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:336) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver$DnsResponseHandler.channelRead(DnsNameResolver.java:1382) \~\[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) \~\[netty-codec-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:97) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) \~\[netty-transport-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) \~\[netty-common-4.1.107.Final.jar:4.1.107.Final\]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) \~\[na:na\]

* 

* 

* 

* 

*
```

my ymal file of another service

```
server:
port: 9090
spring:
boot:
admin:
client:
url: http://localhost:1111
application:
name: GREET_API
eureka:
client:
serviceUrl:
defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
instance:
prefer-ip-address: true
hostname: localhost
management:
endpoints:
web:
exposure:
include: '\*'
```

Tried dns config,added webclient bean,done other config in yamal file,downgraded the spring version but nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

It looks like spring boot admin is trying to guess the URL to use for checking health of your instance by resolving your local hostname.  Try setting it explicitly:

`spring.boot.admin.client.instance.service-base-url=http://localhost:9090`